# How do I interact with same serial device (one serial com interface) from service and client (running at same time)?

Tags: c#, serial-port

Could anyone tell me the appropriate way to design this?

I have one service and one client (client: to configure different settings for serial device and service). Both of them need to interact with the serial device. But both cant connect at the same time (because serial port will then be taken). Client will be started while service is running. The applications do not know when the connections are made (they are in timers and threads), but they can't do it at the same time. I'm thinking of having a dll that both the service and client connects to, that handles this communication. How do I design such a DLL with some kind of command-queue? Maybe there are an easier way or better way to do it? Would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client should connect to your service and perform its actions that way, so that the service can handle any issues of concurrency. Look at WCF for a place to start with that connectivity.

You can't use a shared DLL, because each process (client and server) will be running separately, and trying to run the same code at the same time. The fact that they load the code from the same assembly will not be helpful in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this is as follows:

Service:
* Connects to the device
* Exposes a WCF named-pipe which exposes an API

Client:
* Consumes the API provided by the Service.